# i need country,region,city mapping of maxmind database

Tags: geolocation, maxmind

I am using the maxmind API to get users' location; but the problem is that although they provide the country and city relationship, they seem to provide no relation between region and city.

So anyone who has used the maxmind database, can you please provide me a relationship between city, region, and country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess  you are looking for this [its the mapping u need click here](http://dev.maxmind.com/static/maxmind-region-codes.csv)

Comment: those codes don't seem to map to the data found here: http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City-CSV.zip - please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735768/maxmind-correlating-files-for-lat-lng

Comment: and how did you know about that url? the file doesn't seem to have a link on any of their web pages... perhaps more interestingly, what other files are there that aren't listed?