# MaxMind: Correlating files for lat/lng?

Tags: geolocation, maxmind

I've downloaded the City database from MaxMind found here:

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City-CSV.zip

which contains no latitude/longitude information.  that information seems be in a different file:

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity_CSV/GeoLiteCity-latest.zip

however, when attempting to correlate the two I find that the subdivision codes do not match.  for example the first file contains the line:

> geoname_id,locale_code,continent_code,continent_name,country_iso_code,country_name,subdivision_1_iso_code,subdivision_1_name,subdivision_2_iso_code,subdivision_2_name,city_name,metro_code,time_zone
>
> 3369157,en,AF,Africa,ZA,"South Africa",WC,"Province of the Western
>   Cape",,,"Cape Town",,Africa/Johannesburg

from which one can see that the first political subdivision for Cape Town is WC.  The second file, however, offers the line:

> locId,country,region,city,postalCode,latitude,longitude,metroCode,areaCode
>   244,"ZA","11","Cape Town","",-33.9258,18.4232,,

from which it can be seen that the "region" is "11", not "WC".

so a few questions:

1) how do I correlate these two sources of information?
2) if they cannot be correlated, is there some other file I should be looking at?
3) if MaxMind offers no consistency in their information, is there a better source for a list of city names around the world that offers geolocation information?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latitude and longitude are in the GeoLite2 blocks file, not the locations file. See the [GeoLite2 CSV documentation](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-csv-databases/). The reason for this is that coordinates may be more specific than the (generally) city-level locations in locations file.

The other zip file you link to is for the Legacy CSV and is not intended to be used with GeoLite2